# Collision detection between 2 picture boxes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, timer, collision-detection

I am developing a game and am trying to accomplish collision detection for 2 picture boxes. I have a timer control that is responsible for moving a spike (enemy) towards a box (my character).

Here is my code:

```
private void tmrSpike_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Spike moving left interval
            spike1.Left -= 6;

            if (picSquare.ClientRectangle.IntersectsWith(spike1.ClientRectangle))
                MessageBox.Show("sd");


            if (spike1.Left + spike1.Width < 0)
                spike1.Left = ActiveForm.Width;

        }
```

**PicturesBoxes:**
spike1
picSquare

How do I make it so when the box (character) hits the spike (enemy), it shows an alert?

Note: Only the spike is moving towards the box. The box only jumps up and drops down when the up key is pressed. My game concept is VERY similar to this: http://www.flukedude.com/theimpossiblegame/

Comment: You should not use lots of PictureBoxes.  Instead, use a single hand-drawn control, WPF, or XNA.

Comment: I wanted to give graphics to my game and therefore the best way to do that was to use a picture box.

Comment: Wrong.  The best way to do that in WinForms is to call `Graphics.DrawImage` in a Paint event

Comment: @Farham: One does not follow from the other, though it is a reasonable choice/mistake for a beginner to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong property.  ClientRectangle is the rectangle relative from the control.    You want to use the Bounds property, relative from the container.  Easy to see in the debugger btw, do practice using it.